# Update and create existing data in Django

Tags: python, django

I need to update and, if needed, create elements in a Django update view. Basically, I have a form where I am giving the user the chance of updating a row or inserting one or more new rows.
The problem is that I am having issues in updating the "old" rows. If I update an existing row, it creates a new one.
Here I post some code:

views.py

```
def edit_flight_mission(request, pk):
    mission = Mission.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = EditMissionForm(request.POST or None, instance=mission)
    learning_objectives = LearningObjective.objects.filter(mission_id=mission)
    context = {
        'mission': mission, 
        'form': form,
        'learning_objectives': learning_objectives,
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        learning_obj = request.POST.getlist('learning_obj')
        solo_flight = request.POST.get('solo_flight')

        if form.is_valid():
                mission_obj = form.save()
                if solo_flight == 'solo_flight':
                    mission_obj.solo_flight = True
                    mission_obj.save()
                
        for lo in learning_obj:
            learning_objective, created = LearningObjective.objects.get_or_create(name=lo, mission_id=mission.id)

            if not created:
                learning_objective.name = lo
                learning_objective.save()
                    

    return render(request, 'user/edit_flight_mission.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Mission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    duration_dual = models.DurationField(blank=True, null=True)
    duration_solo = models.DurationField(blank=True, null=True)
    training_course = models.ForeignKey(
        TrainingCourse, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    solo_flight = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)



class LearningObjective(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    mission = models.ForeignKey(Mission, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

forms.py

```
class EditMissionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mission
        fields = ('name', 'duration_dual', 'duration_solo', 'training_course')
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter Mission Name'}),
            'duration_dual': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Duration as HH:MM:SS'}),
            'duration_solo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Duration as HH:MM:SS'}),
            'training_course': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

template

```
{% extends "base.html" %} 
{% block head_title %}
  Edit Flight Mission {{mission.id}}
{% endblock head_title %}
{% block title %} 
  Edit Flight Mission {{mission.id}}
  {% endblock title%}
{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group">
       {{form.as_p}}
    </div>   
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="inputFormRow">
            <label>Learning Objective</label>
            {% for lo in learning_objectives %}
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" value="{{lo.name}}" class="form-control" name="learning_obj" placeholder="Learning Objective">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

            <div id="newRow"></div>
    <div class="form group">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="solo_flight" value="solo_flight" id="flexCheckDefault">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
              Solo Flight
            </label>
          </div>
    </div>
            <button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Add Learning Objective</button>
        </div>

  </div>
  <div class="card-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
      Add New Mission
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
{% endblock content %} 
{% block custom_js %}
<script type="text/javascript">

    // add row
    $("#addRow").click(function () {
        var html = '';
        html += '<div id="inputFormRow">';
        html += '<div class="input-group mb-3">'
        html += '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="learning_obj" placeholder="Learning Objective">'
        html += '<div class="input-group-append">'
        html += '<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="remove">Remove</button>'
        html += '</div></div>'

        $('#newRow').append(html);
    });

    // remove row
    $(document).on('click', '#remove', function () {
        $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
    });
    
</script>
{% endblock custom_js %}
```

The form is updating correctly but the problem is with the part concerning the Learning Objectives basically.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Instead of using get_or_create, try and filter the objects if it doesn't exist, create a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```py
learning_objective, created = LearningObjective.objects.get_or_create(name=lo, mission_id=mission.id)
```

Specifically, the `mission_id=mission.id` part.  If you want to do a lookup to a ForeignKey, you need two underscores.  Therefore, the query is not finding the LearningObjective, thus it is always creating a new one.  But it's not even necessary, since you've already filtered `learning_objectives` by mission (<s>and there, it was done with the correct syntax</s>).

The solution, then is to do this:

```py
learning_objective, created = LearningObjective.objects.get_or_create(name=lo)

if not created:
    learning_objective.name = lo
    learning_objective.save()
```

The solution, though can be done much easier with [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create).  This is the same as what you're doing, but in one line instead of 4.

```py
learning_objective, created = LearningObjective.objects.update_or_create(name=lo, defaults={'name': lo})
```

**Edit**

I think the syntax here is actually not correct.  Change it as follows:

```py
# Change this, 
# learning_objectives = LearningObjective.objects.filter(mission_id=mission)

# To this:
learning_objectives = LearningObjective.objects.filter(mission=mission)
```

**Edit 2**
I'm not sure if this problem is what's causing the learning_objectives not to save, but I now see another error in the html.  You can not have a form within another form.  The `{{ form.as_p }}` is creating another `<form>` tag within the one you already have.  So the form is validating because all the fields of the `{{ form.as_p }}` are there, but those are for the Mission object.  Are the other fields even being submitted?  Check by `print(request.POST)`.  I'm guessing that it will not contain the name field for the learning_obj.

Possible Solutions:

1. Create a form, but *not* a ModelForm, that has everything you want to save from the two different models.
2. Render the `{{ form }}` [manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually), so that the `<form>` tags are not there.  When you submit, *all* inputs with names will be submitted.

Comment: Ok this solution make totally sense and should work but... I really don't know why the data are correctly printed if I try to do so, but they're not saved. As I read in the documentation, the save() is not needed in update_or_create but I can't understand why your solution is not working.

Comment: @GiorgioScarso, I've edited my answer.  I made an error in my original answer.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, it looks like everything is working but not saving in the database. Is there any chance that maybe I need to save this update somewhere?

Comment: No. `update_or_create` should not require a `save()`.  Perhaps put in some print() statements in your view at different locations to see what is happening.

Comment: I tried and it prints me the right entry but, after that, the database keeps the old record in fact. The database is hit because I can see that the updated_at field is updated with the time of the new entry but that learning_objective name field is not updated. I think it's something around it.

Comment: Okay @GiorgioScarso, I've seen another issue with your html that I didn't see before.  You have a form with a form, and that *might* be the issue.  Either way, you cannot nest a form within a form.  I'll update my answer shortly with a possible method.